# Azure Service fabric with file transfer protocol?

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-service-fabric

I ran into a requirement where my service fabric stateless service should listen on a something like a file System communication protocol using which the service would be able to pick file from one location or other running process can would be able to send complete file to the service.

Do we have any way in service fabric for achieving this?

Comment: Do you want to host an FTP server inside SF?

Comment: Yes, the same kind of functionality i want so that my services can keep polling on a particular location and whenever files comes into it, the whole file can be transferred to service.

Comment: If the file isn't too big you can monitor the file system using filesystemwatcher [0] and upload files as byte arrays. Would that work? [0]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx